# How does "had" change the meaning in the sentece "Only once had she put the doctrine of non-interference into practice, when...."

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-order, subject-auxiliary-inversion

First I thought it was the phenomenon of "[Conditional inversion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233992/the-use-of-were-should-had-at-the-beginning-of-sentences-instead-of-if)", but the full sentence does not contain a hypothetical situation but a past occurrence, so that shouldn't be the case (Should I be wrong, correct me, please).

Here's the full sentence (it was too long to put in the title):

> Only once had she put the doctrine of non-interference into practice, when one of her detractors had been besieged for nearly three hours in a may tree by an angry boar-pig.

Comment: Nice example of conditional inversion: "Should I be wrong..." :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the quote:

> Only once had she put the doctrine of non-interference into practice,

This is an example of "subject-auxiliary inversion", where the auxiliary verb ("had") is moved in front of the subject. The reason for the move is that the introductory phrase "only once" has negative force.

[Wikipedia "subject-auxiliary inversion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion)

> Negative inversion
> Another use of subject–auxiliary inversion is in sentences which begin with certain types of expressions which contain a negation or have negative force. For example,
> a. *Jessica will say that at no time.*
> b. *At no time will Jessica say that.* -Subject-auxiliary inversion with a fronted negative expression.

Linked from that Wikipedia article is this one, expanding on the subject:

[Wikipedia "negative inversion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_inversion)

> In linguistics, **negative inversion** is one of many types of subject–auxiliary inversion in English. A negation (e.g. not, no, never, nothing, etc.) **or a word that implies negation (only, hardly, scarcely)** or a phrase containing one of these words precedes the finite auxiliary verb necessitating that the subject and finite verb undergo inversion.

So, in your example, you could start with a non-inverted form:
She had put the doctrine of non-interference into practice only once...
and invert it:
Only once had she put the doctrine of non-interference into practice...

In this case, either form is grammatical. It's the negative sense of "only once" that allows the inversion.

Comment: Only after reading your answer was I able to sleep at ease :) Thanks for your time and your answer Jack!